# Unit testing Scala package object

Tags: scala, unit-testing, package

As per my understanding, `package objects` contain common functionality used across the package. Presumably, these functionalities aren't modified 'as rapidly' as the rest of the codebase; rather only new functionalities would be added (to a package object) with time.

Then is it worthwhile to unit test methods inside a Scala package object?
If yes, then how do I access classes and methods inside package object in my test package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should typically only add `type`s, `val`s, `var`s and `def`s to a *Scala* `package object`; `class`es, `trait`s and `object`s will belong to the same `package`, but they are defined separately. It is a means of defining global variables and functions. (The *Java* ecosystem doesn't really support the concept of purely global data and functions, so *Scala* puts them in a special `object` termed the `package object`.)

For example, say you were designing a package for trigonometry operations, you might have a package object defined something like this:

```
/** My trig library. */
package object trig {

  /** Type used to represent an angle in radian measure. */
  type Angle = Double

  /** Value of PI circle constant. */
  val PI = 3.141592653589793

  /** Calculate angle with specified `opposite` and `adjacent` length values.
   *  @param opposite Length of side opposite the angle in a right-angled triangle.
   *  @param adjacent Length of the side adjacent to the angle in a right-angled triangle.
   *  @return Angle in radians for specified `opposite` and `adjancent` values.
   */
  def atan2(opposite: Double, adjacent: Double): Angle = {
    // Etc...
  }

  // Etc...
}
```

Any classes in your library would be defined in the same package, but as separate elements (typically, in separate files too). For examples:

```
package trig

/** A point in 2D space.
 *
 *  @param x X-axis co-ordinate of this point.
 *  @param y Y-axis co-ordinate of this point.
 */
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)
```

As far as testing is concerned, how often the associated code is expected to be modified shouldn't determine whether or not you write tests for that code. Rather, you should consider the consequences of that code being invalid. In this example, writing a test that verifies that `trig.PI` has the correct value might be a good idea (guarding against the possibility that someone feels inclined to modify its value, accidentally or deliberately) - even though that value should never change. Similarly, you would probably want to write test cases for the `trig.atan2` function. (For example, what does it return when passed two `0.0` argument values, etc.)

When testing the contents of a `package object`, you just reference them as you would in regular code. From code that is in the same package, you just reference the name of the element; otherwise, you would need to prefix the element names with the package. For example:

```
package trig

import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class PackageTest
extends FunSpec {

  describe("trig global elements") {

    // Test value of PI.
    describe("PI") {
      it("must have the correct value") {
        assert(PI === 3.141592653589793")
      }
    }

    // Test atan2 function.
    describe("atan2") {

      it("must return an angle of 0.0 radians if opposite and adjacent are both 0.0") {
        assert(atan2(0.0, 0.0) === 0.0)
      }

      // Etc.
    }

    // Etc.
  }
}
```

For further information, refer to [this guide](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html)...

Answer (score 1):

This answer only answers the part: "how do I access classes and methods inside package object in my test package?"

Ok, I had the following scenario: I was trying to figure out how to reference the a package object from my Junit test classes, which are in the src/test/scala test branch , while the package object is in the src/main/scala main branch.

Say you have a package in the main branch called **com.scala.classes.A** which has a package object A in there that has a method b, and you have a class C in that same package. In the regular branch, class C can simply call method b directly from anywhere in its code. However, in my test code, after creating an object of type C called myC, I could not call method b of package object A by referencing myC.b (its not visible), so how to reference it?

Answer is, all you have to do is to import the package object as if it was a regular object:

import com.scala.classes.A

then simply call

A.b

to test method b